# Is it right to release the temp object after setting self?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, initialization, release, self

Which of the following scenarios is correct coding practice, given that player is (nonatomic, retain), and is synthesized using player = _player.

Scenario A

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
        self.player = mp;
        [mp release];
```

Scenario B

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    self.player = mp;
```

Up until this point I have been using scenario A as a general practice, but I think this may be causing memory leaks within my code.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT 1:

And does the same apply to Timers, they are causing me real hassle. If I'm using the code below is this correct? If timerMap is also (nonatomic, retain), and uses timerMap = _timerMap;

```
self.timerMap = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:fps target:self selector:@selector(updateAnimationTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] autorelease];
```

And when releasing is it fine to just invalidate, or should it be invalidate then release?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576593/objective-c-memory-management-of-instance-members/8576760#8576760) for explanation of what is going on with synthesize and properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scenario A is definitely the way to go, Scenario B will leak `mp`

Source : [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

EDIT 1 :

The code you posted is wrong, it will result in a crash when setting the `timerMap` property again. You must not `autorelease` it

```
self.timerMap = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:fps target:self selector:@selector(updateAnimationTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

When you don't need the timer anymore, just

```
self.timerMap = nil;
```

This will call the `release` method on the timer and will set the pointer to `nil`

Comment: Great thanks, my application must have a memory leak from elsewhere then. Just annoying it's not being picked up by instruments :(

Comment: The Project -> Analyse tool is good for picking up memory leaks (it would have picked up scenario B). Have a try !

Answer (score 1):

Scenario A is correct. Scenario B actually will cause memory leak, it's because self.player = mp; retains the reference counter.

Following code is also correct:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL] autorelease];
self.player = mp;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct memory management, however I just tend to go for:

```
self.player = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
                 initWithContentURL:movieURL] 
                 autorelease];
```

This way I keep all the memory management for that object on one line

EDIT
following edit to question

The timer object as you have it there is **already autorelease**, you shouldn't add `autorelease` to it again. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096836/what-is-the-definition-of-convenience-method-in-regards-to-objective-c) for an explanation of convenience methods.

Comment: Thanks for the info, is there any chance you can help me with the EDIT part of my post too?